# Finding closest number to 0

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers, and I need to find the one that's closest to zero (positive integers take priority over negative ones.)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class CloseToZero {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[] data = {2,3,-2};    
        int curr = 0;    
        int near = data[0];     
        // find the element nearest to zero    
        for ( int i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){    
            curr = data[i] * data[i];     
            if ( curr <= (near * near) )  {     
                near = data[i]; 
            }     
        }    
        System.out.println( near );    
    }    
}
```

Currently I'm getting a result of -2 but I should be getting 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Squaring the number is mathematically elegant, but it significantly constrains the range of numbers that can be accepted in your array.  I would use Math.abs() instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort the array (add one line of code) so the last number you pick up will be positive if the same absolute value is selected for a positive and negative numbers with the same distance.

**Source code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CloseToZero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] data = {2,3,-2};
        int curr = 0;
        int near = data[0]; 
        Arrays.sort(data);      //  add this
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));        
        // find the element nearest to zero
        for ( int i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            System.out.println("dist from " + data[i] + " = " + Math.abs(0 -data[i]));
            curr = data[i] * data[i]; 
            if ( curr <= (near * near) )  { 
                near = data[i];
            } 
        }
        System.out.println( near );
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible runtime complexity, though. It was O(n) before, sort takes more than that.

Comment: it can be simply brute force in 0(n). you just made it nlog. Try binary search approach otherwise.

Comment: No need to sort the array. I solved it without sorting and without searching algorithm  with O(n) time (0.2 sec execution time) . I posted new answer.

Answer (score 23):

This will do it in `O(n)` time:

```
int[] arr = {1,4,5,6,7,-1};

int closestIndex = 0;
int diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    int abs = Math.abs(arr[i]);
    if (abs < diff) {
        closestIndex = i;
        diff = abs;
    } else if (abs == diff && arr[i] > 0 && arr[closestIndex] < 0) {
        //same distance to zero but positive 
        closestIndex =i;
    }
}   
System.out.println(arr[closestIndex ]);
```

Comment: I do not think you strictly need closestIndex. In case of `abs == diff && arr[i] > 0`, you can just do diff = abs, so it simply becomes: `if (abs < diff || (abs == diff && arr[i] > 0) diff = abs;`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using java8:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class CloseToZero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] str = {2,3,-2};
        Arrays.stream(str).filter(i -> i != 0)
                .reduce((a, b) -> abs(a) < abs(b) ? a : (abs(a) == abs(b) ? max(a, b) : b))
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add zero to this list.

Then sort the list

```
Arrays.sort(data);
```

then grab the number before or after the zero and pick the minimum one greater than zero

Comment: this will work but this problem can be solved in O(n) time. your solution requires O(n lg n)

Answer (score 4):

Assumption is that the array `data` has at least 1 value.

```
int closestToZero = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i < data.length; i++ )
{
    if ( Math.abs(data[i]) < Math.abs(data[closestToZero]) ) closestToZero = i;
}
```

The value in `closestToZero` is the index of the value closest to zero, not the value itself.

Comment: Actually I want the logic without using any inbuilt function

Comment: @user3172930 then make the function `return (num*num)/num;`

Comment: Then replace `Math.abs(...)` with your own absolute value method/code.

Comment: That code is wrong. Tried it with `int[] data = {2, 3, -2, 4, 10, 6, -1};`

Comment: @usama8800, wrong the code works perfectly. It returns the index number of the closest to zero, not the number itself!

Answer (score 2):

```
 static int Solve(int N, int[] A){
      int min = A[0];
      for (int i=1; i<N ; i++){
        min = min > Math.abs(0- A[i]) ? Math.abs(0- A[i]) : Math.abs(min);
      }
      return min;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you multiply data[i] with data[i], a value negative and a value positive will have the same impact.
For example, in your example: 2 and -2 will be 4. So, your code is not able to sort as you need.

So, here, it takes -2 as the near value since it has the same "weight" as 2.

Comment: yes that's why I'm looking any new method for given program or any modification internally

Comment: So it should be a good thing to indicate that in your question. Because it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have same answer with different method,Using Collections and abs , we can solved.

```
  static int Solve(int N, int[] A){
      List<Integer> mInt=new ArrayList<>();
        for ( int i=0; i < A.length; i++ ){
            mInt.add(Math.abs(0 -A[i]));
        }
        return Collections.min(mInt);
    }
```

That all,As simple as that

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy to read O(n) solution for this problem.

```
    int bigestNegative = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smalestpositive = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int result = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //if the zero should be considered as result as well
        if ( temperatures[i] == 0 )  { 
           result = 0;
           break;
        } 
        if ( temperatures[i] > 0 && temperatures[i] < smalestpositive )  { 
            smalestpositive = temperatures[i];
        } 
        if ( temperatures[i] < 0 && temperatures[i] > bigestNegative )  { 
            bigestNegative = temperatures[i];
        } 
    }
    if( (Math.abs(bigestNegative)) < (Math.abs(smalestpositive)) && bigestNegative != Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        result = bigestNegative;
    else
        result = smalestpositive;
    System.out.println( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the int array into stream. Then sort it with default sorting order. Then filter greater than zero & peek the first element & print it.
Do it in declarative style which describes 'what to do', not 'how to do'. This style is more readable.

```
int[] data = {2,3,-2};
IntStream.of(data)
    .filter(i -> i>0)
    .sorted()
    .limit(1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

using Set Collection and abs methode to avoid complex algo

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int [] temperature={0};

    ***// will erase double values and order them from small to big***
    Set<Integer> s= new HashSet<Integer>();
    
    if (temperature.length!=0) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<temperature.length; i++) {
        
            ***// push the abs value to the set*** 
            s.add(Math.abs(temperature[i]));
        }
        
        // remove a zero if exists in the set 
        while(s.contains(0)) {
            s.remove(0);
        }
        
        ***// get first (smallest) element of the set : by default it is sorted*** 
        
        if (s.size()!=0) {
            Iterator iter = s.iterator();
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }
        
        else System.out.println(0);
        
        
    }
    
    else System.out.println(0);
    
    

}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a method that gives you the nearest to zero.

- use case 1 : {1,3,-2}  ==> return 1 : use the Math.abs() for comparison and get the least.
- use case 2 : {2,3,-2}  ==> return 2 : use the Math.abs() for comparison and get the Math.abs(least)
- use case 3 : {-2,3,-2} ==> return -2: use the Math.abs() for comparison and get the least.

  ```
  public static double getClosestToZero(double[] liste) {
  // if the list is empty return 0
  if (liste.length != 0) {
      double near = liste[0];
      for (int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
          // here we are using Math.abs to manage the negative and
          // positive number
          if (Math.abs(liste[i]) <= Math.abs(near)) {
              // manage the case when we have two equal neagative numbers
              if (liste[i] == -near) {
                  near = Math.abs(liste[i]);
              } else {
                  near = liste[i];
              }
          }
      }
      return near;
  } else {
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: This is using the same approach as a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23761605/1255289)

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
String res = "";

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int num = arr[0];
        int ClosestValue = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            //for negatives
            if (arr[i] < ClosestValue && arr[i] > num)
            num = arr[i];
            //for positives
            if (arr[i] > ClosestValue && num < ClosestValue)
            num = arr[i];
        }
        res = num;

        System.out.println(res);
```

First of all you need to store all your numbers into an array. After that sort the array --> that's the trick who will make you don't use Math.abs(). Now is time to make a loop that iterates through the array. Knowing that array is sorted is important that you start to make first an IF statement for negatives numbers then for the positives (in this way if you will have two values closest to zero, let suppose -1 and 1 --> will print the positive one).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to deal with this is split the array into positive and negative sort and push the first two items from both the arrays into another array. Have fun!

```
function closeToZeroTwo(arr){
let arrNeg = arr.filter(x => x < 0).sort();
let arrPos = arr.filter(x => x > 0).sort();
let retArr = []; 
retArr.push(arrNeg[0], arrPos[0]);
console.log(retArr)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to just sort that array in ascending order suppose input is like :

```
int[] array = {10,-5,5,2,7,-4,28,65,95,85,12,45};
```

then after sorting it will gives output like:

```
{-5,-4,2,5,7,10,12,28,45,65,85,95,}
```

and for positive integer number, the Closest Positive number is: **2**

Logic :

```
public class Closest {

public static int getClosestToZero(int[] a) {

    int temp=0;
    //following for is used for sorting an array in ascending nubmer
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length-i-1; j++) {
            if (a[j]>a[j+1]) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //to check sorted array with negative & positive  values
    System.out.print("{");
    for(int number:a)
        System.out.print(number + ",");

    System.out.print("}\n");
    //logic for check closest positive and Integer
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i]<0 && a[i+1]>0) {
            temp = a[i+1];
        }
    } 
    return temp;
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {10,-5,5,2,7,-4,28,65,95,85,12,45};
    int closets =getClosestToZero(array);
    System.out.println("The Closest Positive number is : "+closets);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static void closestToZero(){
    int[] arr = {45,-4,-12,-2,7,4};
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int closest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        int value = arr[i];
        int abs = Math.abs(value);
        if (abs < max){
            max = abs;
            closest = value;
        }else if (abs == max){
            if (value > closest){
                closest = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Return a positive integer if two absolute values are the same.

Answer (score -1):

package solution;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

```
public static void trier(int tab[]) {

    int tmp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (tab.length - 1); i++) {

        for(int j = (i+1); j< tab.length; j++) {

            if(tab[i] > tab[j]) {
                tmp = tab[i];
                tab[i] = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tmp;

            }

        }

    }

    int prochePositif = TableauPositif(tab);

    int procheNegatif = TableauNegatif(tab);

    System.out.println(distanceDeZero(procheNegatif,prochePositif));



}
public static int TableauNegatif(int tab[]) {

    int taille = TailleNegatif(tab);


    int tabNegatif[] = new int[taille];


    for(int i = 0; i< tabNegatif.length; i++) {

        tabNegatif[i] = tab[i];
    }
    int max = tabNegatif[0];

    for(int i = 0; i <tabNegatif.length; i++) {

        if(max < tabNegatif[i])
            max = tabNegatif[i];
    }
    return max;


}
public static int TableauPositif(int tab[]) {

    int taille = TailleNegatif(tab);

    if(tab[taille] ==0)
        taille+=1;


    int taillepositif = TaillePositif(tab);

    int tabPositif[] = new int[taillepositif];



    for(int i = 0; i < tabPositif.length; i++) {


        tabPositif[i] = tab[i + taille];

    }
    int min = tabPositif[0];
    for(int i = 0; i< tabPositif.length; i++) {

        if(min > tabPositif[i])
            min = tabPositif[i];
    }
    return min;


}

public static int TailleNegatif(int tab[]) {
    int cpt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        if(tab[i] < 0) {
            cpt +=1;

        }
    }
    return cpt;

}
public static int TaillePositif(int tab[]) {
    int cpt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        if(tab[i] > 0) {
            cpt +=1;

        }
    }
    return cpt;

}

public static int distanceDeZero(int v1, int v2) {

    int absv1 = v1 * (-1);

    if(absv1 < v2)
        return v1;

    else if(absv1 > v2)
        return v2;
    else 
        return v2;



}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int t[] = {6,5,8,8,-2,-5,0,-3,-5,9,7,4};

    Solution.trier(t);


}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

We have to find the Closest number to zero.
The given array can have negative values also.
So the easiest approach would append the '0' in the given array and sort it and return the element next to '0'

1. append the 0
2. Sort the Array
3. Return the element next to 0.

`

```
N = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

arr.append(0)
arr.sort()

zeroIndex = arr.index(0)
print(arr[zeroIndex + 1])
```

--> If this solution leaves corner cases please let me know also.

`

Comment: This approach was [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23761205/1255289). As pointed out in comments, it is slower than other approaches.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't wanna use the inbuilt library function use the below code (just an and condition with your existing code)-

```
public class CloseToZero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = {2,3,-2,-1,1};
        int curr = 0;
        int near = data[0];
        // find the element nearest to zero
        for ( int i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            curr = data[i] * data[i];
            if ( curr <= (near * near) && !((curr - (near * near) == 0) && data[i] < 0))  {
                    near = data[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println( near );
    }
}
```

`!((curr - (near * near) == 0) && data[i] < 0)` : skip asignment if if `near` and `curr` is just opposit in sign and the `curr` is negative

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int find(int[] ints) {
    if (ints==null) return 0;
    int min= ints[0];   //a random value initialisation 
    for (int k=0;k<ints.length;k++) {
        // if a positive value is matched it is prioritized              
        if (ints[k]==Math.abs(min) || Math.abs(ints[k])<Math.abs(min)) 
            min=ints[k];            
    }
    return  min;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int check() {

    int target = 0;
    int[] myArray = { 40, 20, 100, 30, -1, 70, -10, 500 };
    int result = myArray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] == target) {
            result = myArray[i];
            return result;
        }
        if (myArray[i] > 0 && result >= (myArray[i] - target)) {
            result = myArray[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have added a check for the positive number itself.
Please share your views folks!!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ClosesttoZero {
    
      static int closZero(int[] ints) {
        
        int result=ints[0];
        for(int i=1;i<ints.length;i++) {
            if(Math.abs(result)>=Math.abs(ints[i])) {
                result=Math.abs(ints[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
        
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        int[] ints= {1,1,5,8,4,-9,0,6,7,1};
        int result=ClosesttoZero.closZero(ints);
        System.out.println(result);
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done simply by making all numbers positive using absolute value then sort the Array:

```
        int[] arr = {9, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1, -2};

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = Math.abs(arr[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println("Closest value to 0 = " + arr[0]);
```

Comment: This is wrong, `int[] arr = {9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1, -2};` returns `1`, which is not in the array.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.math.*;

class Solution {

    static double closestToZero(double[] ts) {
        if (ts.length == 0)
            return 0;

        double closestToZero = ts[0];
        double absClosest = Math.abs(closestToZero);

        for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
            double absValue = Math.abs(ts[i]);

            if (absValue < absClosest || absValue == absClosest && ts[i] > 0) {
                closestToZero = ts[i];
                absClosest = absValue;
            }
        }

        return closestToZero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//My solution priorizing positive numbers contraint

int closestToZero = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//or we

    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
                
            if (Math.abs(arrayInt[i]) < closestToZero 
                        || Math.abs(closestToZero) == Math.abs(arrayInt[i]) && arrayInt[i] > 0 ) {
                    
                closestToZero = arrayInt[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static int nearToZero(int[] A){
Arrays.sort(A);
int ans = 0;
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int num: list){
    if(newList.contains(num)) toRemove.add(num);
    else newList.add(num);
}
list.removeAll(toRemove);
for(int num : list){
    if(num == 0 ) return 0;
    if(ans == 0 )ans = num;
    if(num < 0 && ans < num) ans = num;
    if(num < ans) ans = num;
    if(num > 0 && Math.abs(ans) >= num) ans = num;
}
return ans;
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your code will make it more helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry I just based my answer to an exercise in the hackerearth the requirements are choose the number closest to zero but eliminate the duplicate integer in the array not really sure if this is what he really wanted but it works in the hackerearth exercise with the mentioned requirement

Comment: Specifically, how does your code work, and why is it a superior option to the other 25 answers that have been posted since the question was asked in 2014. You should [edit] your question to include supplementary details or it's likely to be deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Powerful solution in java :

```
static int closestToZero(int[] ints) {

    if((ints == null) || (ints.length == 0)){
        return 0;
    }
    int min = Arrays.stream(ints).min().getAsInt();
    int abs = min;
    for(int v:ints){
        if(v == Math.abs(min)){ 
          abs = Math.abs(min);
        }
    }


    return abs;
}
```